# WPF MVVM Data Binding issue

Tags: c#, mvvm, data-binding, datagrid, mvp

My `ViewModel` is as follows:

```cs
public class ShipDataCollectViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    //private ObservableCollection<Item> _scannedItems;
    //private Item _scanningItem;

    public ObservableCollection<Item> ScannedItems
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    public Item ScanningItem 
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    public ShipDataCollectViewModel()
    {
        ScannedItems = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
        ScanningItem = new Item();
        AddItemCommand = new RelayCommand(AddItem, CanAddItem);
    }

    private RelayCommand _addItemCommand;

    public RelayCommand AddItemCommand { get; private set; }

    private void AddItem()
    {
        //var item = new Item { ItemNo = _scanningItem.ItemNo, Qty = _scanningItem.Qty, Box = _scanningItem.Box, SerialNo = _scanningItem.SerialNo };
        //ScannedItems.Add(item);
        //Cannot use the following code, it will overwrite all the ObservableCollection's items if exist.
        ScannedItems.Add(ScanningItem);
    }

    private bool CanAddItem()
    {
        return true;
    }

}
```

`View` is as follows:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="114" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="722">
        <Label Content="Customer No:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" Margin="5,5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="94"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" Margin="104,5,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="108"/>
        <Label Content="PO No:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" Margin="258,5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="94"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" Margin="354,5,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="108"/>
        <Label Content="SO No:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" Margin="5,40,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="94"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" Margin="104,40,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="108"/>
        <Label Content="Vendor:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" Margin="255,40,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="94"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" Margin="354,40,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="108"/>
        <Label Content="Invoice No:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" Margin="5,72,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="94"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" Margin="104,72,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="108"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="221" Margin="10,127,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="722">
        <Label Content="Shipping Detail" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="207" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <Label Content="Item:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" Margin="10,42,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="57"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" Margin="79,42,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ScanningItem.ItemNo}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="210"/>
        <Label Content="Qty:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" Margin="10,76,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="57"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" Margin="79,76,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ScanningItem.Qty}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="89"/>
        <Label Content="Box:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" Margin="10,109,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="57"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" Margin="79,109,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ScanningItem.Box}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="210"/>
        <Label Content="Serial No:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" Margin="10,142,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="64"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" Margin="79,142,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ScanningItem.SerialNo}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="210"/>
        <CheckBox Content="Item LookUp" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="310,42,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="153.42"/>
        <Button Content="Add" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="310,142,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="339" Margin="19,353,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="723">
        <Label Content="Scanned Items" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="207" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,42,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                  Height="260" Width="535" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding ScannedItems}"
                  Style="{StaticResource AzureDataGrid}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ItemNo}"  Header="ItemNo"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Qty}" Header="Qty"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Box}" Header="Box"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding SerialNo}" Header="SerialNo"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <Button Content="Delete Selected" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" Margin="10,307,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="141"/>
    </Grid>
    <Button Content="Exit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="28,307,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="151"/>
    <Button Content="Send File" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="276,307,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="151"/>
</Grid>
```

View Class is as follows:

```cs
public partial class ShipDataCollect : MetroWindow
{
    private ShipDataCollectViewModel viewModel;

    public ShipDataCollect()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        viewModel = new ShipDataCollectViewModel();
        DataContext = viewModel;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        viewModel.AddItemCommand.Execute(null);
    }
}
```

Purpose:

- Add Item, and display it in the `DataGrid` View.
  but got the following Problem.
- Add first Item ->Item A {Item A, 10, Box1, SerialNo1}, it will display correctly in `DataGrid`.
- Add Second Item-> Item B {Item B, 10, Box2, SerialNo2}. after click Add button,  two items will be displayed in the Data Grid, but both of them are Item B.

Comment: `viewModel.AddItemCommand.Execute(null);` facepalm.  You're supposed to bind the ICommand to the button, not execute it from the codebehind.  Your code does not reflect your claims as well.  AFAICT, you add the same instance of Item (ScanningItem) each time to the collection.  This is a mess.  Try creating a barebones prototype that does only this, and you'll see where you are screwing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an attempt to add the same **current** item (`ScanningItem`) instance multiple times.
Consider creating a new item after adding the previous one to the collection:

```
private void AddItem()
{
    ScannedItems.Add(ScanningItem);
    ScanningItem = new Item();
}
```

Please introduce firing of `PropertyChanged` event when the value of `ScanningItem` property is changed to propagate changes to `View` (data binding mechanism). For example, convert `ScanningItem` from auto-implement property to property with backing field as follows (assuming that MVVM Light is used):

```
private Item scanningItem;
public Item ScanningItem
{
    get
    {
        return scanningItem;
    }

    private set
    {
        if (Equals(scanningItem, value))
        {
            return;
        }

        scanningItem = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("ScanningItem");
    }
}
```